# Get crx file with HTTP request

Tags: google-chrome

I would like to download packaged crx files from Google.
I tried

```
https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3D<ID>%26uc
```

But is return `204 No Content`.

I know the site http://chrome-extension-downloader.com/ and the extension give-me-crx, But I must get it through HTTP request, is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the source of Chrome extension source viewer.

Comment: [Question](/q/7184793 "How to download a CRX file from the Chrome web store for a given ID?") this refers to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need "&prodversion=32" at the end of the URL.

```
https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3D<ID>%26uc&prodversion=32
```